# Layout não ocupa tela inteira

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou montando um layout e o layout não está ocupando a tela inteira. Tentei de várias formas, mas nunca é possível que ocupe, então não está cabendo tudo que preciso.

Problema acontece ao colocar o scrollview, é possível ter a tela toda, com ele?

Segue XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative_rota">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_view_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/ondeEstou"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_origem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:hint="@string/action_my_location"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/destino"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_destino"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:hint="@string/action_type_destination"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/companhia"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_companhia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:completionThreshold="3"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_a_pe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_walk_white_48px" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_bike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_bike_white_48px" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_carro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_car_white_48px" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_publico"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_bus_white_48px" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Segue imagem de como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que ocupe toda a tela, para que fique bem distribuído.
Somente na vertical mesmo.

agradeço a ajuda!

-EDIT-
XML alterado, mas ao colocar o scrollview, para que seja possível o scroll da tela com o teclado aberto, ele me limita ao marcado na imagem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_rota"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fundo_3"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="app.Rota">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_top"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:completionThreshold="3"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_a_pe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/fundo_3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_walk_white_48px" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_bike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/fundo_3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_bike_white_48px" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_carro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/fundo_3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_car_white_48px" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/trasporte_publico"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/fundo_3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
            android:onClick="chamarRota"
            android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_bus_white_48px" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_view_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/ondeEstou"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_origem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:hint="@string/action_my_location"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/destino"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_destino"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:hint="@string/action_type_destination"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="@string/companhia"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rota_edt_companhia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é quando coloco o scrollview, seria possível fazer com o scrollview? Pois quando coloco não vai para a tela toda.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se não tiver o scrollview, consigo fazer conforme a resposta abaixo. Consigo manipular o layout pela tela toda. Mas quando coloco o scrollview, por exemplo sendo "pai" de todo o layout, ele me limita, neste pequeno espaço da imagem, conseguiu entender?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não sei o que é viewport. O scrollview eu gostaria que fosse possível o scroll pela tela toda, quando o teclado estiver aberto, então acredito que ele deveria estar dentro do relativelayout, vou colocar o XML, "novo", mas ainda sem o scrollview.

Comment: Tenta colocar o scrollView como root, assim ScrollView > RelativeLayout > LinearLayout e faça o resto como na resposta abaixo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentei, não consigo entender o motivo de não não deixar mover pela tela toda

Comment: É verdade, faz assim remove o Relative e deixa só ScrollView > LinearLayout, veja se funciona, é que estou sem o androidstudio aqui, mas amanhã no escritorio vou testar também qualquer coisa ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como o scrollview só pode ter um "filho" acrescentei outro linearlayout, na vertical, ele realmente me dá uma área maior de trabalho e melhor distribuição da tela. Mas mesmo assim, não é a tela toda, mas já melhorou muuito! E tranquilo, aqui tá sem pressa haha valeu demais já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu não tenho os seus drawables e values, e você não mostrou exatamente como gostaria que o layout ficasse, improvisei em cima do código. Coloquei cores no background dos layouts (para diferenciar) e usei imagens do Studio.

Compare os dois pra entender onde se equivocou.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/relative_rota">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_view_top_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="@string/ondeEstou"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/rota_edt_origem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:hint="@string/action_my_location"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="@string/destino"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/rota_edt_destino"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:hint="@string/action_type_destination"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/edt_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/txt_left_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="@string/companhia"
        android:textColor="@color/txt_text"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rota_edt_companhia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/edt_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/edt_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edt_top_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/edt_text"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:completionThreshold="3"
    android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" 
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_top"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trasporte_a_pe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:onClick="chamarRota"
        android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_transp_walk_white_48px"
        tools:src="?android:attr/actionModePasteDrawable" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trasporte_bike"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:onClick="chamarRota"
        android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trasporte_carro"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:onClick="chamarRota"
        android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="?android:attr/actionModeCutDrawable" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trasporte_publico"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/place_autocomplete_search_hint"
        android:onClick="chamarRota"
        android:padding="@dimen/place_autocomplete_button_padding"
        android:src="?android:attr/alertDialogIcon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Algumas dicas em relação ao código:

1. Dentro de RelativeLayout, as views são posicionadas uma EM RELAÇÃO a outra.
2. No caso, as alturas (height) da maioria das views deve ser wrap_content, com exceção da raiz.
3. layout_alignParent... faz o ALINHAMENTO com a view-pai e não mexe nas dimensões do elemento.
4. margin e padding são bons pra separar views umas das outras. Usar para posicionar em relação a view-pai, especialmente, usando valores específicos, pode causar problemas como sobreposição das views.
5. parent não é a view anterior, mas é a view-pai, dentro do qual a view está.

Comment: Layout ficou excelente, basicamente o que eu quero. Mas não consigo fazer isso com o scrollview, pois seria bom tê-lo, para que não seja necessário sempre abaixar o teclado para ver os campos. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Se entendi a pergunta, você coloca a scrollview como parent do viewgroup que quer que role quando não houver espaço suficiente. Ou seja, não precisa colocar por fora do relativelayout, podendo ficar por fora apenas do linearlayout